# Design text file using c# .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to generate text file.For that i use 'StreamWriter' it creates fine. Now i nead to design that text file with text. I need Shop name font size is bold and 16. other text font are as normal. And also i want to generate table in text file.This is my sample code. I use to create text file.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(d:\sample1.txt))
{
     sw.Write("ShopName");    
     sw.Write("BillNo");                  
}
```

Comment: You cannot have formatting of text in a standard .txt file. If you want to do this you should look at some other file formats that support this (RTF, possibly even HTML if only the look of the file is important etc.)

Comment: Is possible to take print of RTF by using c#

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Windows standard Textfiles also known as .txt do not Support formatting Text. You can create a RTF file if you need formatting. There are librarys supporting you in this task: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98062/RTF-Document-Constructor-Library

Depending on your needs you could also create an html file with formatting.

Comment: Is possible to take print of RTF by using c#

Comment: This is a seperate question, but yes http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;812425

Comment: +1 for the HTML suggestion. Far more simpler to generated than RTF

Answer (score 2):

StreamWriter is for writing text in it's plainest form. To make the text bold you're gonna have to use some sort of markup; HTML,RTF for example

Answer (score 0):

You don't format text that way in a text file, and can't do proper tables neither. You need to write in another format using the proper Assemblies. You could be writing a rtf file, doc file or a PDF for example...

Answer (score 0):

Pure Text files can not contain any format information (like bold)

So you have to choose another format. HTML can be created by StreamWriter as it is quite "simple". RTF would work too, but is a bit more complex so better look out for a specialized solution instead. There are a lot of other formats, like docx, pdf etc.

Which one you choose should depend on the purpose of that file. Who should read it? Where? In a Browser? Chose HTML. On a Windows Machine? RTF could work. Commandline? Perhaps Ansi-Format can work but might require special Drivers on DOS.

But the essence is: pure TXT does not allow what you want to achieve